# Ext JS: How to reload multiple stores?

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, reload

I've defined several stores inside `ViewModel` and I've a button to reload all of them together. Instead of creating multiple `var` to assing with `Ext.getStore('sampleStore')`, I want to select all only with one `var` and using `reload()` only once.

Here is a not **fully** working snippet;

```
refreshPanel: function () {   
        // This way only one of stores is reloading, its sampleStore1.
        var panelStores = Ext.getStore('sampleStore1', 'sampleStore2', 'sampleStore3');

        panelStores.reload();
    }
```

and here is stores which defined in `ViewModel`:

```
stores: {
        // I've tried to give a storeId name but ofcourse did not work!
        //storeId: 'adminbonus',

        sampleStore1: {
            storeId: 'sampleStore1',
            ...
        },

        sampleStore2: {
            storeId: 'sampleStore2',
            ...
        },

        sampleStore3: {
            storeId: 'sampleStore3',
            ...
        },
    },

//And using several formulas with chainedstore or bindTo configs
formulas: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
    var panelStores = ['sampleStore1', 'sampleStore2', 'sampleStore3'];

    Ext.each(panelStores, function(eachStore) {
         var store = Ext.getStore(eachStore);
            if(store){
                store.reload();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!